# Instance a class in the same namespace as a regex

Tags: ruby

I've written some classes that contain a set of configurations and actions and each class is in it's own namespace (module).  I have a regex constant in each namespace that I want to use to match to an input which will determine which class I'll instance (array is used to set the priority order).  I want to instance the class `<namespace>::PrintSomeWorld` but can't seem to directly get the namespace of the matched regex.

Question: Is there a command to get the namespace of an object?  The code below shows my current solution where I'm passing the module name as part of the `MY_REGEX` data object.  However, it would be cleaner to just *know* the namespace of the matched object.

```
module MyHelloTest
  MY_REGEX = {mname: name, mregex: /test/}
  class PrintSomeWorld
    def initialize
      p "hello world!"
    end
  end
end

module MyGoodbyeTest
  MY_REGEX = {mname: name, mregex: /goodbye/}
  class PrintSomeWorld
    def initialize
      p "goodbye world!"
    end
  end
end

mytests = [MyHelloTest::MY_REGEX, MyGoodbyeTest::MY_REGEX]
found_regex = mytests.find {|f| f[:mregex].match("this is a goodbye")}
Object.const_get(found_regex[:mname])::PrintSomeWorld.new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may be possible to indeed extract this kind of info from the regexes, that approach suffers from micro-management. Calling code knows too much about structure of the modules and has to do too much unnecessary work. Adding just *the smallest bit* of OOP makes the problem go away.

```
module MyHelloTest
  MY_REGEX = /test/

  def self.match(str)
    MY_REGEX.match(str)
  end

  def self.print
    PrintSomeWorld.new
  end

  class PrintSomeWorld
    def initialize
      p "hello world!"
    end
  end
end

module MyGoodbyeTest
  MY_REGEX = /goodbye/

  def self.match(str)
    MY_REGEX.match(str)
  end

  def self.print
    PrintSomeWorld.new
  end

  class PrintSomeWorld
    def initialize
      p "goodbye world!"
    end
  end
end

mytests = [MyHelloTest, MyGoodbyeTest]
found_module = mytests.find {|f| f.match("this is a goodbye")}
found_module.print
# >> "goodbye world!"
```

Comment: Ahh! I forgot that I could treat the modules as objects... that cleans things up.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Module::nesting](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-c-nesting).

```
module MyHelloTest
  class PrintSomeWorld
    Module.nesting
  end
end
  #=> [MyHelloTest::PrintSomeWorld, MyHelloTest]
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I really understood your question, but if you already have the object and it has one module, as you described, you can use:

```
your_object.class.parent
```

Comment: That didn't work for me when the object was of type regex.